# Web development: How to 'store' pages in the browsers and prevent them from reloading every time when navigating between them

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, navigation

I am new to web development and am creating a web app using pure JS. I am using Firebase and Express.js routing for the backend functionalities. This is kind of a simple blogging service, so there is naturally a lot of navigation between pages.

Current issue: Whenever users move back and forth between pages, the pages refresh every time, even if there are no changes whatsoever. This is critical user experience issue in 2020. I guess this is because I am sending a html file for each URL request, but don't know what will be the workaround.

Question: How do I make sure that the rendered pages are 'stored' in the user's browser and reloads only when there are meaningful changes in the contents?

Excuse the high-level question...picked up programming just 3 months ago. :) Would appreciate any directional advice on where to start looking at.

Comment: In this case you should share your code, so anyone who want help you could see more clearly the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is where JS frameworks will help you to make SPA applications. Essentially all your pages are loaded when a user first hits your app and then dynamically shows/hides different pages to avoid a page refresh.

You can get away with using javascript to manually add/remove a css class to the different page elements like the following

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

<div class="hidden">
    ...page 1 (not shown)
</div>
<div>
    ...page 2 (shown)
</div>
<div class="hidden"
    ...page 3 (not shown)
</div>
```

It's a lightweight and simple solution but keep in mind that this will not change the url any. This also means that you'll need to put everything that you want to be "stored" in one html file. I think most SPA JS frameworks will do something like "example.com/#/contact" or "example.com/#/about" with the hashtags in there and that way the url can help the user to see what page they are on.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the reply! Just wanted to ask you a couple of follow-up questions:
1. If I am using pure JS and ExpressJS router only, will this issue be largely unavoidable? (
2. Any recos for JS framework to get away from this issue? I am planning to learn React--will it have answers to the issue?

Comment: You are very welcome! If it works out for you please consider marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah you can create a SPA with React. But if you just want to use pure vanilla javascript then my code in this answer would allow you to do that.